# Advice requested about configuring nginx for https

Tags: http, nginx, https, centos7

I'd like to ask for advice about configuring nginx and https for a Flask server (Centos 7, nginx 1.20.1).

I've defined a RESTful API which works as designed. I'd now like the user to be able to use any of the following addresses when calling the API:

http://mysiteapi.com

http://www.mysiteapi.com

https://mysiteapi.com

https://www.mysiteapi.com

I set up a generic nginx.conf file which worked fine for the first two addresses (http). I then ran sudo certbot --nginx -d mysite.com -d [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com). The https addresses now work but the http addresses give a 405 error. This nginx.conf file is shown below.

Is there anything obviously wrong about the 301 redirection here? More generally, is there scope to tidy up the file and reduce the number of 'server' blocks? I'm learning my way around nginx and would appreciate any guidance.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
#include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server 
    {
        client_max_body_size 8M;
        server_name mysiteapi.com;
        location / 
        {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/andrew/myproject/myproject.sock;  
        }
    
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysiteapi.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysiteapi.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }
    
    server 
    {
        client_max_body_size 8M;
        server_name www.mysiteapi.com;
        location / 
        {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/andrew/myproject/myproject.sock;  
        }
    
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysiteapi.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysiteapi.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }

    server 
    {
        if ($host = mysiteapi.com) 
        {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        server_name mysiteapi.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
    
    server 
    {
        if ($host = www.mysiteapi.com) 
        {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        server_name www.mysiteapi.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
   }
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you get an HTTP 405 error with the plain HTTP requests, but I can guess it can happened because of requests methods other than `GET` - an HTTP 301 redirect will change any request method to the `GET` one, and to prevent it you should use an [HTTP 308](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308) redirect instead. But as I understand from your question you don't need any redirects at all, both HTTP and HTTPS schemes should be served equally, and if that is you want to achieve, you can significantly simplify your server block:

```
server {
    server_name mysiteapi.com www.mysiteapi.com;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ... # rest of the config here
}
```

Here I want to refer [this](https://serverfault.com/a/896555/498657) answer:

> I don't allow certbot to create my web server configurations. I frankly don't trust it to get it right, since it's already doing some not very efficient practices.

I do the same for my servers, so I suggest you to add this location to your nginx config (you can use any suitable directory instead of `/var/www`):

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

and use a `certbot` for certificate issuing/renewing only:

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www -d mysiteapi.com -d www.mysiteapi.com
```